# Proper Java handleRequest() method signature for Amazon Echo/Alexa on Amazon Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create an [Amazon Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function implemented in Java to work with Amazon Echo/[Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit).  I'm using Eclipse Mars as the IDE.

Here's what my `LambdaFunctionHandler`, which will receive the requests from Alexa, looks like:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<SpeechletRequestEnvelope, SpeechletResponse> {

    @Override
    public SpeechletResponse handleRequest(SpeechletRequestEnvelope input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, when trying to test this with sample JSON input from Alexa, I get the error in Eclipse:

> {"errorMessage":"An error occurred during JSON parsing","errorType":"java.lang.RuntimeException","stackTrace":[],"cause":{"errorMessage":"Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;","errorType":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError","stackTrace":["java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native
>   Method)","java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)","java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._findFields(AnnotatedClass.java:689)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveFields(AnnotatedClass.java:470)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:282)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:390)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collect(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:243)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:197)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:110)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:15)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(DeserializationConfig.java:703)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:330)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:265)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:245)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:439)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._prefetchRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:1588)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.(ObjectReader.java:185)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._newReader(ObjectMapper.java:558)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.reader(ObjectMapper.java:3098)"],"cause":{"errorMessage":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper","errorType":"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException","stackTrace":["java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)","java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)","java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)","java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native
>   Method)","java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)","java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._findFields(AnnotatedClass.java:689)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveFields(AnnotatedClass.java:470)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:282)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:390)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collect(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:243)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:197)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:110)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:15)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(DeserializationConfig.java:703)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:330)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:265)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:245)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:439)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._prefetchRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:1588)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.(ObjectReader.java:185)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._newReader(ObjectMapper.java:558)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.reader(ObjectMapper.java:3098)"]}}}

Here's my JSON input (taken from the [TestColors example](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-lambda-function) online):

```
{
  "session": {
    "new": false,
    "sessionId": "session1234",
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": null
    },
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.[unique-value-here]"
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "request": {
    "intent": {
      "slots": {
        "Color": {
          "name": "Color",
          "value": "red"
        }
      },
      "name": "MyColorIsIntent"
    },
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "request5678"
  }
}
```

So, apparently Amazon `SpeechletRequestEnvelope` isn't the correct input class for `handleRequest()`.

What is the correct method signature for `handleRequest()` to receive requests from Alexa?

I can't find a Java example for Amazon Lambda that works with Alexa/Echo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a full working example:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
        byte serializedSpeechletRequest[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        SpeechletRequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = SpeechletRequestEnvelope.fromJson(serializedSpeechletRequest);
        SpeechletRequest speechletRequest = requestEnvelope.getRequest();

        if (speechletRequest instanceof IntentRequest) {
            IntentRequest ir = (IntentRequest) speechletRequest;
            String outString = "IntentRequest name: " + ir.getIntent().getName();
            context.getLogger().log(outString);
            output.write(outString.getBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this class implements `RequestStreamHandler`, NOT `RequestHandler`.

Using the input JSON from the question, the `output.write(outString.getBytes())` will result in the output to the Eclipse AWS Lambda console:

> ==================== FUNCTION OUTPUT ====================
>
> IntentRequest name: MyColorIsIntent

...while `context.getLogger().log(outString);` results in the same line being written to the Amazon Lambda console online.

You also need to make sure you have a folder `/lib` in your project, and the following JARs need to be included:

- commons-codec-1.6.jar
- commons-lang3-3.x.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar
- jackson-core-2.3.2.jar
- jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
- JakartaCommons-IO-2.4.jar
- joda-time-2.3.jar
- log4j.1.2.17.jar
- servlet-api-3.0.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.4.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.4.jar
- alexa-skills-kit-1.0.jar

These JARs can be downloaded from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/), or from the "third-party" subfolder in the [AlexaSkillsKit.zip](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/using-the-alexa-skills-kit-samples-java).

In Eclipse, you need to refresh the project so it sees the JAR files in the `/lib` directory (just hit F5), and then add the JARs to the Java build path:

1. Right-click on the root of the Lambda project in Eclipse
2. Click "Properties"
3. Select "Java Build Path"
4. Select the "Libraries" tab
5. Click "Add JARs"
6. Browse to the "lib"
7. Select all JARs in the "lib" folder, and click "Ok" until you're back to the main Eclipse screen

Thanks to @jephers for the pointer to this great tutorial on Github where I pieced a lot of this together from:

https://github.com/jjaquinta/EchoProofOfConcepts/tree/master/jo.echo.lambda

Answer (score 1):

I extend jo.echo.lambda.utils.SpeechletLambda (https://github.com/jjaquinta/EchoProofOfConcepts/blob/master/jo.echo.lambda/jo/echo/lambda/utils/SpeechletLambda.java) and this works for me:

```
@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream,
        OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException
{
    super.handleRequest(inputStream, outputStream, context);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Where is the SpeechletLambda.java from, originally?  Could you provide a link to the source on Amazon site?

Comment: The documentation for node.js is good - for Java, not so good. Here is jo's tutorial on creating a skill with Java and Lambda: https://github.com/jjaquinta/EchoProofOfConcepts/tree/master/jo.echo.lambda

Comment: Ah, thanks!  The tutorial on Github is definitely helpful.  Looks like there were at least a few items going wrong.  I'll type up a complete answer for what was going on, but definitely +1 for the resources!